# How to insert dictionaries into an empty dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, dictionary

Im working with a BFS algorithm, i have this output for this code

```
>     for node in graph.keys():
>         print(BFS(graph, node))
```

Output

```
{1: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 9: 7, 5: 8, 10: 9}
{2: 0, 8: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 9: 4, 5: 5, 10: 6, 1: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1}
{3: 0, 4: 1, 9: 2, 5: 3, 10: 4, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1}
{4: 0, 9: 1, 5: 2, 10: 3, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1}
{5: 0, 10: 1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1}
{6: 0, 7: 1, 2: 2, 8: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 9: 6, 5: 7, 10: 8, 1: -1}
{7: 0, 2: 1, 8: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 9: 5, 5: 6, 10: 7, 1: -1, 6: -1}
{8: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 9: 3, 5: 4, 10: 5, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1}
{9: 0, 5: 1, 10: 2, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1}
{10: 0, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1}
```

I need to add these dictionaries into one single dictionary, like this

```
dic = {
    1: {1: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 9: 7, 5: 8, 10: 9},
    2: {2: 0, 8: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 9: 4, 5: 5, 10: 6, 1: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1},
    3: {3: 0, 4: 1, 9: 2, 5: 3, 10: 4, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
    4: {4: 0, 9: 1, 5: 2, 10: 3, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
    5: {5: 0, 10: 1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1},
    6: {6: 0, 7: 1, 2: 2, 8: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 9: 6, 5: 7, 10: 8, 1: -1},
    7: {7: 0, 2: 1, 8: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 9: 5, 5: 6, 10: 7, 1: -1, 6: -1},
    8: {8: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 9: 3, 5: 4, 10: 5, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1},
    9: {9: 0, 5: 1, 10: 2, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
   10: {10: 0, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1}
}
```

I assume to create an empty dictionary, and add the nodes as keys and the output of the code as value. But it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use dict comprehension:

```
{node:BFS(graph, node) for node in graph.keys()}
```

Comment: Perfect bro, thanks. Can i ask you something else?
I applied pandas in this dictionary, but the rows of the output appears in disorder (1,6,3,5,4, etc etc) Do you know how order it?

Comment: @Andres, replace `graph.keys()` with `sorted(graph.keys())`.

Comment: @Andres dict does not guarantee an order, so you need to do some sorting over pandas rows

Comment: Yes, you're right, i have to do it in pandas. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `enumerate()` to generate `dict` using dict comprehension:

```
res = {i + 1: BFS(graph, node) for i, node in enumerate(graph.keys())}
```

---

Whooops, I've missed that you want to use `node` as key of dict. @Andrei already answered with code which do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dic = {}
for num, node in enumerate(graph.keys()):
    dic[num] = BFS(graph, node)
    print(BFS(graph, node))
```